# Xaml desktop application connect to Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to connect to a *Azure Mobile service* with my WPF Desktop application.
I added all the possible Azure references to my wpf application but i cant use

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
```

Can you connect to a Mobile service with a non mobile application. 
I want to connect to this service because of saving files to the BLOB.

Should i use a *mobile service*, note that i will build a mobile app in the near future and want to be able to use the data saved with the desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Mobile Service Client SDK is for building classic desktop applications. They're for building Windows Store Apps.

I would actually recommend that you use **Storage Client Library**. Since you mentioned that you would like to use this library to save files in blob storage, I would recommend using Storage Client library instead. In order to upload files in blob storage, even mobile service SDK/client library is also using the same thing.

Storage client library gets installed with Windows Azure SDK and you could also get the same through Nuget as well.